# C - comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')

Tags: c

I'm very new at C and I'm having a problem using function `strstr`.
Make gives me a warning that I do not understand, anybody can explain ?

> **warning:** comparison between pointer and integer (`char *` and `int`)
>   `if (strstr(reference, number_start) == 1)` warning generated.

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void) {
    char reference[]        = "34,37";
    char number[]           = "34567890123456";
    char number_start[]     = {number[0], number[1], '\0'};

    if (strstr(reference, number_start) == 1) {
        printf("Yup, iit's workin'\n");
    } else {
        printf("Try again, wookie\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strstr()` isn't just a predicate, it returns a pointer to the instance of the substring if it found it.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to use `strcmp` function, don't you?

Comment: nope, I wanted to check if the first two digits of the number var were present in the reference var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strstr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) return a pointer to the first substring if found, and `NULL` if not found.

Replace

```
if (strstr(reference, number_start) == 1) {
```

with

```
if (strstr(reference, number_start) != NULL) {
```

to check if `number_start` is in `reference`.

Answer (score 0):

Do `int(strstr(a,b))` if strstr is not null for index.